DAX measure to calculate compliance percentage for each sales document
I am trying to create a DAX measure in PowerBI. Below are my tables structure:
Sales:
created_date.  sales_doc_no.  delivery_date
Orders:
sales_doc_no.  delivery_date
Date:
created_date
Sales to Orders is a many to one relationship on sales_doc_no
Sales to Date is a many to one relationship on created_date
I am trying to calculate a DAX measure : compliant_sales_doc_count which is a ratio of compliant sales docs to total sales docs at a sales doc level
Sales_Compliant_Count = 
var CompliantDocs = CALCULATE(
DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK(sales[doc_no]),
FILTER(orders,
    DATEDIFF(
        'orders'[delivery_date],
        LOOKUPVALUE('sales'[created_date], 'sales'[doc_no], 'orders'[doc_no]),
        DAY
    ) < 14
)
)
RETURN
CompliantDocs

Sales_nonCompliant_Count = 
var NonCompliantDocs = CALCULATE(
DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK(sales[doc_no]),
FILTER(orders,
    DATEDIFF(
        'orders'[delivery_date],
        LOOKUPVALUE('sales'[created_date], 'sales'[doc_no], 'orders'[doc_no]),
        DAY
    ) >= 14
    )
)
RETURN
NonCompliantDocs

When I try to calculate the ratio it is causing a cross join since either of the values can be blank. I tried using coalesce, isblank but the cross join still remains the same.
my end goal is to create a visual in the below way:
sales_doc_no (from orders table).   created_date (from date table).   delivery_date  (from orders table).  sales_compliant_count.   sales_non_compliant_count.   compliance_percentage

I think you have an issue with the context with the way you designed your relationships.
You may need to adjust your measures like below :
Sales_Compliant_Count = 
VAR CompliantDocs = 
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales'[sales_doc_no]),
        FILTER(
            'Orders',
            'Orders'[delivery_date] <> BLANK() && 
            'Sales'[created_date] <> BLANK() &&
            DATEDIFF(
                'Sales'[created_date],
                'Orders'[delivery_date],
                DAY
            ) < 14
        )
    )
RETURN
CompliantDocs

Then :
Sales_NonCompliant_Count = 
VAR NonCompliantDocs = 
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales'[sales_doc_no]),
        FILTER(
            'Orders',
            'Orders'[delivery_date] <> BLANK() && 
            'Sales'[created_date] <> BLANK() &&
            DATEDIFF(
                'Sales'[created_date],
                'Orders'[delivery_date],
                DAY
            ) >= 14
        )
    )
RETURN
NonCompliantDocs

and  the final measure for the compliance percentage:
Compliance_Percentage = 
VAR TotalDocs = 
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales'[sales_doc_no])

VAR CompliantDocs = [Sales_Compliant_Count]
VAR NonCompliantDocs = [Sales_NonCompliant_Count]

RETURN
IF(
    TotalDocs = 0,
    BLANK(),
    CompliantDocs / TotalDocs * 100
)

